# jquery ajax request not responding

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm a newbie at `asp.net` and trying to understand `ajax` responses. I have following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=cbx_pep.ClientID%>').change(function () {
        var mSis = $('#<%=cbx_pep.ClientID%>').val();
        getRCT(mSis);
    });
});

function getRCT(mez_sis) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Staff/PEX.aspx/GetTempInfo',
        method: 'get',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: '{d_val:' + mez_sis + '}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

and that's my server side code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetTempInfo(string d_val)
{
    string str = d_val;
    return str;
}
```

I'm repeatedly getting error. Appreciate for help.

Comment: And what does the error say ?

Comment: [object Object] says only.

Comment: Try using the console when debugging, not alerts, and you'll get something meaningful from that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as mybrithname said, You have yo use `method: 'post'` and then your json is invalid, you have a missing quotes there:

It should be something like this

```
data: '{d_val:\"' + myVar + '\"}',
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `method: 'post'` if you are going to send data to the server, which you are doing in `data: '{d_val:' + mez_sis + '}'`

Comment: @SertanPekel okay check your console in chrome or firefox and see what error you see. After that try to fix it. It will show you where is the problem.